# Reverse DNS lookup returns “not found 3(nxdomain)”

Tags: dns

I perform a reverse DNS lookup from my server using the IP address 40.77.167.119 (Bing Bot search engine) and get **not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)**:

```
host 40.77.167.119
Host 119.167.77.40.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

[Online reverse DNS services](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3A40.77.167.119&run=toolpage) returns correct result `msnbot-40-77-167-119.search.msn.com`

Please tell me if this is a problem with my server or my hosting or Bing?

Comment: ive just checked a couple of my servers and get the same nxdomain error for the arpa record - you should delete your post on [so]

Comment: I can't figure out where to look for the problem. Why do some services give the correct result, but my and your server don't.

Answer (score 1):

We have been seeing the same on our servers staring last month:

```
$ host 40.77.167.119
Host 119.167.77.40.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ host 40.77.167.119 8.8.8.8
119.167.77.40.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer msnbot-40-77-167-119.search.msn.com.
```

According to Linode support, the problem is a DNSSEC misconfiguration affecting the 40.77.167.0/24 subnet which has resulted in those addresses being excluded from the Linode DNS resolvers.  In that case the fault lies with Microsoft.

I don't pretend to understand the specifics:
https://dnsviz.net/d/150.167.77.40.in-addr.arpa/dnssec/

Comment: My server is also on Linode. Bing support stopped responding after I mentioned Linode)